# addEventListener only firing once

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm adding a click event to all links that match a particular selector as part of a JS module I'm creating. It looks something like this.

```
var Lightbox = (function () {

  var showLightbox = function () {
    // this does stuff
  };

  var init = function () {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(options.selector);
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        showLightbox();
      }, false);
    }  
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

})();

Lightbox.init();
```

On first load the any links on the page that match the selector work. There is also a `closeLightbox()` method that works fine. However when clicking the links for a second time nothing happens. I get no console errors – nothing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong when adding the event listener?

**EDIT:** I've updated the code to remove some redundant methods and have pasted the full code here: http://pastebin.com/mC8pSAV2

Comment: With the code you've supplied, there is no way to tell if anything happens when you click on one of the links. The event listener might first. It imght call `showLightbox()`. Some of the unspecified "stuff" that function might be done (with no visible effect). You need to supply a test case that actually demonstrates the problem (and adding some extra console.log statements to trace what happens wouldn't be a bad idea).

Comment: E.g., the code you've shown won't do what you describe, you've over-trimmed it.

Comment: Side note: Unless you need to prevent `showLightBox` from receiving the event argument and being called with `this` referring to the link, `links[i].addEventListener('click', function() { showLightbox(); }, false);` is a long way to write `links[i].addEventListener('click', showLightbox, false);`.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, full code here: http://pastebin.com/4dK5ZszW – the reference to Helpers just contains a few helper methods for grabbing file contents etc. I am just getting my head around JS and the idea of writing modular code – so please forgive the inaccuracies in best practice.

Comment: I've updated the pastebin code to remove some of the redundant methods to *hopefully* make things a little simpler: http://pastebin.com/mC8pSAV2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reassigning `innerHTML` of the whole document:

```
document.body.innerHTML += response;
```

on the link `click`. That wipes out all existing DOM elements with their events and creates new DOM structure with no `click`s assigned.